# Ola Hallengren Database Backup keeps failing (for both SYSTEM and USER databases)

Tags: backup, ola-hallengren, system-databases

Both USER and SYSTEM backup database jobs have been running fine until some weeks back when I checked my alerts (bearing in mind that this is on DEV where I do my own testing etc).

I am just confused as to where the error lies as I checked the path, security, permissions, etc. All have full control over the folder, subfolders, and files.

SYSTEM DATABASE BACKUP ERROR MESSAGE:
[image]

USER DATABASE BACKUP ERROR MESSAGE:
[image]

Any advice/help would be really appreciated! Please do let me know if you would like me to provide any further information :)

Thanks in advance commUNITY!

Comment: Hi @KinShah - Thank you for your response :) Thats one of the first thing I checked and mentioned above on the post. The user 'CM-CORP-TH\devsqlint17agt' has full control permission to the folder, subfolders, and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I should share the answer to my question I posted yesterday - So after multiple series of tests and, back and forth with permissions/access rights I chose my last option which was to recreate the backup job. I went ahead with this and now my system backup job is up and running successfully. Thanks, @KinShah for your input, was appreciated :)